# D2L Hide/Lock Content?

Tags: desire2learn

In automating a content workflow for students in Desire2Learn I am trying to hide and unhide content based on external events. In D2L REST APIs how are content objects and learning objects  locked/unlocked or hidden/unhidden?

Answer (score 0):

The isHidden and isLocked fields are controlled by the calls using the [ContentDataObject](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/content.html#Content.ContentObjectData) such as the [call to update a topic](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/content.html#put--d2l-api-le-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-%28D2LID-orgUnitId%29-content-topics-%28D2LID-topicId%29).